# Grdview to excel and save so dialog box does not show

Tags: vb.net

i have the following code. which creates and saves an excel file with the content in grdview4 which is great. however at the end of the application it displays a disalog box which i do not want. is there anyways to get it do the dialog box does not show?

```
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"

        '  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=""C:\EchoBACs\RejectedBACSBACs\rejectedBacs" & NewDate & ".xls")

        '  Response.TransmitFile("C:\rejectedBacs" & NewDate & ".xls")
        Response.Charset = ""
        Me.EnableViewState = False
        Dim oStringWriter As New System.IO.StringWriter
        Dim oHtmlTextWriter As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter)
        GridView4.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF")

        GridView4.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter)
        Dim helpme As String = oStringWriter.ToString()
      '  Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString())

        ' HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
        File.WriteAllText("C:\EchoBACs\RejectedBACS\rejectedBacs" & NewDate & ".xls", helpme)

        oHtmlTextWriter.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use response in that case, this will ask the Save as dialog box. If you want to save the file to your disk without any prompt do something like this. I am giving you in C#

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid();
grid.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
grid.DataSource = datatable;
grid.DataMember = datatable.TableName;
grid.DataBind();
 using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter ("d:\\temp\test.xls"))
 {
     using (HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
     {
           grid.RenderControl(hw);
     }
}
```